# Event value keeps changing when an object equal to the event is changed

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

The following code is being used to map an event with an object:

```
//shortened the function for better visibility
moveToolbar.on("graphic-move-stop", function (evt) {
    oldGraphicMove = evt.graphic;          
    oldGraphicMove.geometry.rings[0][0] = 42173;
    newGraphicMove = evt.graphic;
});
```

However when changing the value of oldGraphicMove the value of the event is also changing to mimic it even though no change is being made to the event itself. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that oldGraphicMove points to the same object as evt.graphic.
You need to make a copy of evt.graphic.

`oldGraphicMove = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(evt.graphic));` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

the objects are passed by reference. to pass it by value you can use the anonymous function or you need to clone object

```
//shortened the function for better visibility
moveToolbar.on("graphic-move-stop", function (evt) {
  oldGraphicMove = (function(x){
    var obj = Object.create( x );
    obj.geometry.rings[0][0] = 42173;
    return obj;
  })(evt.graphic);
  newGraphicMove = evt.graphic;
});
```